# Hibernate using different instances for getter and setter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts2

i'm stuck with the following problem. I'm using struts2 in conjunction with Spring and Hibernate. I have an Entity with a transient field:

```java
@Entity
public class Company implements java.io.Serializable {
   private Locale locale;

   public final void setLocale(final Locale locale) {
     this.locale = locale;
     LOG.debug("set locale: " + this.locale +  "(" + System.identityHashCode(this) + ")");
   }

   @Transient
   public Locale getLocale() {
     LOG.debug("get locale: " + locale +  "(" + System.identityHashCode(this) + ")");
    return locale;
   }

}
```

My Problem is when the tomcat is freshly started and i call `getLocale()` immediately after calling `setLocale()` on the seemingly same instance the hash code in setter and getter is different and so the getter does not know about the locale set in the setter. When reloading the page that calls getter and setter once or twice the getter and setter use the same instance and all works well from then on. So has anybody an idea what my problem could be besides my dullness?

Comment: It looks like you would like a transient field to be persistent, which is precisely what Transient avoids. Where does the entity come from? Where's your code?